# How do I create typewriting effect in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

What's the simplest way to create text typewriting (or actually 'computer typing with blinking at the end) on a wordpress web page?
I think the lamest option is animated gif, but I'm sure there is a simple (I know there are a bunch of not so simple ways) to incorporate it onto a picture. A word press plugin will be perfect, but I couldn't find one

Comment: Are you trying to put an animation effect on a page, in a Wordpress template, or Wordpress content?  Why does it have to be in a GIF?  Or does it?  The question isn't entirely clear, can you add details as to what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: Actually, have you even thought about a javascript idea that does a loop with turning a div on, and a div off which you fill with a grey color?

Comment: A shortcode plugin that does this would quite easy to create. Your question is very vague though. I suggest you read through the [shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) pages, then have a go at writing a plugin by yourself. Come back here if you run into any difficulties along the way.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sjptra88/

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be with the jQuery library typed.js . Check out this demo: http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/

Does this satisfy your needs?

Kindly Regards,

Philip